# Intensity of sound and pitch perception

Tags: acoustics

I read in "Handbook of Acoustics" by Alton Everest

> A famous acoustician, Harvey Fletcher, found that playing pure tones
>   of 168 and 318 Hz at a modest level produces a very discordant sound.
>   At a high intensity, however, the ear hears the pure tones in the
>   150-300 Hz octave relationship as a pleasant sound. We cannot equate
>   frequency and pitch, but they are analogous.

I try to reproduce it but I can't. (tuning two sine waves to the said frequencies and listening at low and high level). For what intensity this phenomenon takes place? Is there a table that presents the change of perceived frequency and the gain?

From the article about [Fletcher–Munson curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%E2%80%93Munson_curves) at Wikipedia:

> The article also comments on the large differences apparent in the
>   low-frequency region, which remain unexplained. Possible explanations
>   are:
>
> The equipment used was not properly calibrated.
>   The criteria used for judging equal loudness at different frequencies had differed.
>   Subjects were not properly rested for days in advance, or were exposed to loud noise in traveling to the tests which tensed the
>   tensor tympani and stapedius muscles controlling low-frequency
>   mechanical coupling.

Is the reference accurate?

Comment: Does Everest give a citation for Fletcher's work? Or have you found one yourself? That is the canonical way to find out what Fletcher actually did.

Comment: @rob I checked the reference at the 4th edition (I have the 3rd here in translation) and the reference is there. Thanks, I investigate the issue now.

Comment: If you edit the citation into your question, another user might have some insight. The passage you quote from Wikipedia seems to be about measuring the subjective loudness of low-frequency pitches, but the passage from Everest seems to describe some kind of nonlinear frequency-shifting effect.

Comment: @rob I tried another experiment from the same book (sum and difference of a 23 and 24kHz in the non-linearity of inner ear) and couldn't make it work either. For me poor selected and non reproducible experiments. I give up the book, and everything I read  should be triple checked for whatever reasons of exaggerations. Discordant chords that become consonant in high levels is just nonsense.

Comment: @rob In this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407836/sound-pitch-why-the-louder-the-higher?rq=1 the experiment seems to be quite subjective and it does not worth to be described as an accurate phenomenon. (as in the handbook I mentioned)